# Intent sent when upload completes

Tags: android, file-upload, upload

Is there any Broadcast intent / message sent when we upload documents/images on our android devices.I am looking for something similar to the DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE that is sent when Download is complete.
The requirement of my app is to monitor all uploads that are done on the phone and hence I am looking for any Broadcast message / intent that I can listen to

Comment: How are you uploading something to Android?

Comment: After some 'googling' I recommend you to try to do something with "TrafficStats", like, determining that a transaction is finished if there is no new packets transmitted during some time. Also, some StackOverflow answers point about using NTP and working in low-level. Goog Luck!

Comment: @GerSoto , I tried using the TrafficStats.getTotalTxPackets to track the bytes transmitted in order to track any upload data. My requirements is to stop upload of any file through an app. Unfortunately using the TrafficStats API's lets me monitor the number of bytes and is not specific to uploading a file. Any idea how to detect uploading of a file programatically in Android ?

Comment: I think that you can't block as you want, so selective. Every App is a user in Android, and from one user you can't block another user, although you are root. Have you tried to find any app which convert your device into kiosk mode? To use it, you have to be root, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Use  [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask {

```
      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
           // upload file code
      }      

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // start new intent
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
      }

      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
      }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

Comment: Quoting the very reference page you link to: _AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)_

Answer (score 0):

Just use an AsyncTask.

From some time to now, I'm realizing that "Services" and "Broadcast Messages" functionalities were improved by the AsyncTask's capabilities.

Comment: My app needs to handle any upload that happens on the phone (its not only limited to uploading of files through my app)..Will an Aysnc task help in this scenario ?

Comment: Quoting the [AsyncTask reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html): _AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)_.

Comment: No, AsyncTask doesn't cover it. Please, clarify this at your question, to avoid misunderstandings. I can't answer you at this moment without some reading, but I think that "App-user" politics, is difficult to know something about other apps status if it doesn't intent it to you (with direct intents or Broadcast Messages).